# Companimation: CSS3 Animations Only Working on Load

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, animation

I'm using [Mike Fowler's companimation library for compass](http://mikefowler.me/companimation/), but my animations will not work at all in FireFox (they work fine in Chrome though).  When the document is first displayed, the animation will fire, but the animation will not fire when elements are shown/hidden via jQuery.

[Here's a plugin I made using the library that has animations](http://srsgores.github.io/jquery-hash-tabs).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

i'm using JQueryKeyframes. it work.
try it

```
https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes
```

you can customize function complete

```
$('selector').playKeyframe({
    name: "keyframe_name", 
    duration: time*1000,
    timingFunction: 'linear', 
    delay: 0,
    //repeat: 0, 
    direction: 'normal', 
    fillMode: 'forwards',
    complete: function(){ 

        $('selector').css('-webkit-animation', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Are you saying that in order to get animations to work in FF when elements are shown/removed, I need to use a library?  Then why does this work in webkit browsers without a JS library?